# How to get Feature from Drug's Similarity matrix?

Tags: charts, embedding, feature-engineering

I want to create feature information(like feature matrix) based only on the similarity information of each drug, but is it possible to use the method using truncated PCA without any abnormalities?

If there is a problem, what are the other ways?

I've tried embedding using random walk, but I'm looking for other ways because I don't seem to get the results I want.